# Как поставить картинку в тайтеле у название стронций?

Tags: веб-программирование

Сделал сайт не знаю как поменять картинку в title (возможно рядом)
Вот фото, какой картинки я имею виду:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стро́нций — химический элемент с атомным номером 38[4]. (С) Wiki https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Стронций

Comment: А если серьезно, то погуглите Favicon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это называется фавикон (favicon). Имеет расширение .ico. Вставляется в секцию `<head>` вот таким образом:

`<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico"/>`

Comment: можно ничего, никуда не вставлять, если картинка названа по "умолчанию" - браузер ее и без заголовка запросит(это по факту так, как в стандарте - хз) =) и еще, расширение ico совершенно не означает формат ico https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(формат_файла). т.е. если я просто сменю расширение JPEG на .ico - ничего не взлетит